# RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'back_top_quill.R.003': Input to rig type must be a chain of 2 or more bones. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm currently super new to Blender, and have been following a tutorial I've found on YouTube on how to make Sonic, and one of the top back spines of the little guy is giving me a bit of trouble, apparently. When I try generating my rig (edited from the usual human metarig if I remember correctly) I get the error, "RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'Tail.003': Input to rig type must be a chain of 2 or more bones.
Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'"

If anyone could help me out, I would appreciate it!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I highly suggest you to upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here with us, so that we can dig in and investigate ourselves.

Comment: Done! Took me a bit to finally get it to upload, but the project file is now up on the Exchange, @L0Lock.

Comment: @t-hedgie you forgot to post the link here.

Comment: My apologies, @L0Lock, I got the link up now.

Comment: Ok, I think I got the main issue. Posting an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your metarig in Pose Mode, I see that you set the Rigify Type on the Tail.003 bone:

[image: issue]

Rigify Types need to be set on the top level parent of the bone chain. So, remove it from Tail.003 and put it on Tail.001 instead:

[image: fix]

This fixes the `` issue. But now we have another one when generating the rig: `Error: Generation has thrown an exception:`.

Going to the menu Window > Toggle System Console allows us to see that a lot of bones are having issues, and all of them are from the face:

```py
Fetch rig.
Clear rig animation data.
Create main WGTS: 0.001
Duplicate rig: 0.011
CONFLICT: bone ORG-nose.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.T.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose.L.001)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-nose.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.T.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose.R.001)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-ear.L.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.L.001) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.L.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-ear.L.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.L.001) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.L.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-ear.L.004 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.L.001) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.L.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-ear.L.004 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.L.002) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.L.004)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-ear.R.004 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.R.001) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.R.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-ear.R.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.R.001) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.R.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-ear.R.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.R.001) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.R.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-ear.R.004 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.R.002) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-ear.R.004)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-chin.L is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-jaw.L is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-jaw.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.B.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.B.L is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.B.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.B.L is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L.001)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L.001)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L.001)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.L.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L.001) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.L.003)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-jaw.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-chin.R is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-jaw.R is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.B.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.B.R is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-temple.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.B.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-cheek.B.R is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-cheek.B.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R.001)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R.001)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R.001)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-brow.T.R.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R.001) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-brow.T.R.003)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-chin is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-chin)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-chin.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-jaw) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-chin)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-lid.B.L.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.T.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-lid.B.L is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.T.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-lid.B.L.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.T.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-lid.B.L.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.T.L) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.B.L)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-lid.B.R is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.T.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-lid.B.R.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.T.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-lid.B.R.001 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.T.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-lid.B.R.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.T.R) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-lid.B.R)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-nose.004 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-nose.003 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-nose.002 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose.002)

CONFLICT: bone ORG-nose.004 is claimed by rigs <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.stretchy_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose.002) and <class 'rigify.rigs.skin.basic_chain.Rig'> (ORG-nose.004)

Instantiate rigs: 0.010
Rigify: failed to generate rig.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\ui.py", line 798, in execute
    generate.generate_rig(context, metarig)
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\generate.py", line 617, in generate_rig
    raise e
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\generate.py", line 605, in generate_rig
    generator.generate()
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\generate.py", line 465, in generate
    self.invoke_initialize()
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\base_generate.py", line 318, in invoke_initialize
    self.__run_object_stage('initialize')
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\base_generate.py", line 284, in __run_object_stage
    self.plugin_list[i].rigify_invoke_stage(method_name)
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\utils\metaclass.py", line 128, in rigify_invoke_stage
    getattr(self, stage)()
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\utils\node_merger.py", line 106, in initialize
    group.build(final_nodes)
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\utils\node_merger.py", line 200, in build
    best.merge_done()
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\rigs\skin\skin_nodes.py", line 178, in merge_done
    super().merge_done()
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\utils\node_merger.py", line 284, in merge_done
    child.merge_done()
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\rigs\skin\skin_nodes.py", line 180, in merge_done
    self.find_mirror_siblings()
  File "C:\AppInstall\Blender\stable\blender-3.3.1-windows-x64\3.3\scripts\addons\rigify\rigs\skin\skin_nodes.py", line 195, in find_mirror_siblings
    assert self.mirror_siblings[self.name_split] is self
AssertionError
Error: Generation has thrown an exception:
```

Simple solution: delete the face bones from the metarig. And if you need them later, you can add a new temporary metarig in object mode, then copy paste the face from the temporary metarig to the one you have been working on.

After that, it should generate without errors. But we do have one last issue:

[image: last issue]

The generated rig has the wrong scale, because your metarig scale isn't 1:1:1. To fix this, select your metarig in Object Mode, press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Scale, and generate the rig again:

[image: fixed scale]

After that, you still have a lot of bones in your metarig that generate nothing: it's because you didn't set their Rigify rig type. But you already know how to fix that

Comment: Okay, just did that- seems I did in fact get a generation error, mainly "Generation has thrown an exception:" with no name to a piece, etc. mentioned. It's just that phrase and that's it.

Comment: Answer edited! Let me know how it goes.